# Error compiling F90 using Makefile

Tags: makefile, fortran, gnu-make, gfortran

My source f90 codes include:

(1) module: dat_io.f90, dimconvert.f90

(2) main: elastic_2D.f90

The following is my Makefile:

```
FC=gfortran
FCFLAGS=-Wall -O3
FLFLAGS=-mcmodel=large
SRCS = $(wildcard *.f90)
EXES = $(patsubst %.f90,%,$(SRCS))
%.o: %.f90
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -c $<
SRC_CODE=\
        dat_io.f90\
        dimconvert.f90\
        elastic_2D.f90
OBJ = $(SRC_CODE:%.f90=%.o)
elastic: $(OBJ)
    $(FC) $^ $(FLFLAGS) -o $@
clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.mod *~ $(EXES)
all: clean elastic
```

Although I used `-mcmodel=large` to avoid "relocation truncated to fit" error, when I `make` it, some errors still pop up says:

```
elastic_2D.o: In function `MAIN__':
elastic_2D.f90:(.text+0x167): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.bss'
elastic_2D.f90:(.text+0x1ce): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.bss'
elastic_2D.f90:(.text+0x23a): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.bss'
elastic_2D.f90:(.text+0x2b9): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.bss'
elastic_2D.f90:(.text+0x320): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.bss'
elastic_2D.f90:(.text+0x38c): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.bss'
elastic_2D.f90:(.text+0x40b): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.bss'
elastic_2D.f90:(.text+0x472): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.bss'
elastic_2D.f90:(.text+0x4de): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.bss'
elastic_2D.f90:(.text+0x530): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.bss'
elastic_2D.f90:(.text+0x5e8): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [elastic] Error 1
```

What is wrong here and how do I revise it?

Comment: Do you have lots of static arrays, in common etc.?

Comment: No, all variables are normally declared, like int, double, character...

Comment: That doesn't mean "no".  Without representative code there's probably not much to say.  But do you need to use `-mcmodel` when compiling, not just when linking?  (I don't know how gfortran treats that option.)

Comment: Will the .mod files affect the result, because I only included .o files in my Makefile. I don't know how to include them in Makefile, or it doesn't matter because they've already compiled to obj files.

Comment: In such a basic setting the `.mod` files are nothing to worry about.  Unrelated to your problem, almost certainly.

Comment: I think I should use -mcmodel, because when I compile my code in the command line, I use "gfortran -mcmodel=large -o exeName myCode.f90" which is pretty okay but not ok when without -mcmodel. Also, I put all the modules in one file (i.e. the main program) when compiling in the command line.

Comment: My point wasn't clear.  What I meant to say is: you aren't using that option when compiling, just when linking.  If you need to, you should change the recipe for compiling.

Comment: Ok, so you mean add that option to both compiling and linking processes?

Comment: Can you try to make a reduced sample of your Fortan Code to reproduce the issue? Please try to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using an `-mcmodel=` option it is important to use this when compiling as well as when linking.  In the Makefile here, `-mcmodel=large` is given (through `FLFLAGS`) only at the link stage.

Adding the option to `FCFLAGS` here will use it at compile time also.